# What does it mean when a textmate scope is strikethrough text in VSCode 'Tokens and Scopes Inspector'

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, textmate

I am using the tokens and scopes inspector tool in vscode. Some of my text (code) is not taking the expected color. When I used the inspector, I see that the expected scope is actually strikethrough. I assume this is indicating something, but I have no clue what.

Observe the following image at the bottom under the 'foreground' field...

[image]

Comment: I believe it means its over-ridden by a semantic token type, but I am having issues finding solid info on the resolution order/precedence and what not as well. I have some textmate tokens I want to still work, as the semantic tokens that are overriding it aren't as specific as the original tokens.

Answer (score 3):

I just read this and found a solution shortly after, so I thought I would share in case this might help someone else. Try adding this to your settings.json

```
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false
```

Comment: Extremely useful thank you! Without it, it seems like the theme is overriding some custom syntax highlighting definitions.

For posterity, the source of this recommendation is the VSCode guide on syntax highlighting itself: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#enablement-of-semantic-highlighting. More interestingly you can enable it for a specific language only.